# Is tomcat running, python script

Tags: python, tomcat, system-administration

Is there any python code or script which can check is tomcat running or something that can replace this code?

```
'ps -ef | grep ytm1 | grep tomcat | grep -v grep'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psutil` is a cross-platform library that retrieves information about running processes and system utilization.

```
import psutil
running_programm = "tomcat" #Whatever the name of your programm
pythons_psutil = []
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        if p.name() == running_programm:
            pythons_psutil.append(p)
    except psutil.Error:
        pass
if pythons_psutil :
    print "It's running !!"
```